# Magento currency switch displaying incorrect currency in footer, but displays correct in header

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu, currency

I am experiencing a strange issue with the currency dropdown switch in Magento. It displays and works correctly in the header, but the one in the footer displaying incorrectly. It changes the currency correctly, as the one in the header changes when i switch it in the footer, but the footer dropdown displays the wrong currency. If I choose EUR, GBP displays, if I choose GBP, EUR displays!

I created currency_footer.phtml within /directory (same location as currency_top.phtml) and I duplicated the code with the only change for the div class it's contained in. Here is the code in currency_footer.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Currency switcher
 *
 * @see Mage_Directory_Block_Currency
 */
?>
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
<div class="tm_footer_currency">
<label class="btn"><?php echo $this->__('Currency:') ?></label>
    <select name="currency" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Within my xml document I have added the block within the footer:

```
    <reference name="footer"><!-- To ADD In Footer -->
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
        <block type="directory/currency" name="currency_end" as="currency_end" template="directory/currency_footer.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

Then within footer.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_end') ?>
```

I have tried using a different name for the block, cleared the cache & re-indexed the data, but nothing I've tried works.

Any ideas why it would display incorrectly, but still work right?

Another issue which may have nothing to do with it, I changed the share with friend page into a pop up, and when i close the pop up, the currency dropdown in the header duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

you need to put code in `<reference>` tag and after that you will call the <`?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_end') ?>` in `footer.phtml`

Here code

```
<reference name="footer">
<block type="directory/currency" name="currency_end" as="currency_end" 
template="directory/currency_footer.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Or,

In other  procedure, you `would not need xml` code and just call the `below code in footer.phtml`
Here code is

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('directory/currency')
->setTemplate('directory/currency_footer.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry I wasn't clear, I had put the code in reference and the block is showing up, but it isn't working correctly.